# Prove if $a+b=c+d$ and $e+f=g+h$, then $a+e+b+f=c+g+d+h$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to prove that if $a+b=c+d$ and $e+f=g+h$, then $a+e+b+f=c+g+d+h$?

(For example, $a=2, b=3, c=1, d=4, e=4, f=5,g=2, h=7$, then $2+4+3+5=1+2+4+7$.)

Comment: Hint: $a+b+e+f = c+d+e+f$

Comment: By the way you have different equations to prove (or disprove) in your title and content

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,  it is possible

$$ a + b + e + f =(a + b) + (e + f) =  (a + b) + (g + h) = (c + d) + g + h = c + d + g + h $$